# How can I show how a package can be installed, manually

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

Sometimes, when I run a command that belongs to an `apt` package that isn't installed, it'll show how it can be installed. For example:

```
root@localhost:~# traceroute

Command 'traceroute' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install inetutils-traceroute  # version 2:1.9.4-11, or
apt install traceroute            # version 1:2.1.0-2
```

Is there any way to show this manually, since when I try to run `traceroute` with something like `subprocess` and `python`, this isn't shown?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can display this with:

```
/usr/lib/command-not-found traceroute
```

Comment: This also seems useful to find out which package a command belongs to that _is_ installed.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Hm... for installed command, it shows me only the **location** of these commands (like `/usr/sbin/traceroute`); doesn't show which package the command belongs to.

Comment: Ah, it shows the location if the command is installed system-wide, but if it's built locally from source then it shows the package that would provide the command of the same name.